# Select from db but CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 2 requested, with a size of 2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this function that I use to find rows that contains substrings in their name. But I get error, although using log.v I can see the results are returned ok. Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Here is my findAlbum function:

```
public ArrayList<Albums> findAlbum(String keyword) {
        ArrayList<Albums> albums = new ArrayList<Albums>();

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorites " + "WHERE "
                + ALB_NAME + " LIKE '%" + keyword + "%';", null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        if (c != null) {
            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_NAME));
                    String singer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_SINGER));
                    String genre = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_GENRE));
                    String mix = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_MIX));
                    String thumb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_THUMB));
                    albums.add(new Albums(id, name, singer, genre, mix, thumb));
                    Log.v("--", "FOUND FROM DB:" + albums.get(i).getTAG_NAME());
                    c.moveToNext();
                }

            }
        }
        return albums;
    }
```

And LogCat output:

```
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.myapp.functions.DatabaseHelper.findAlbum(DatabaseHelper.java:75)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.myapp.activities.Favorites$1.afterTextChanged(Favorites.java:67)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7655)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8057)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:900)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:663)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:188)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:149)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-04 08:30:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(7773):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to get item at index 2 but size of Cursor is 2 and indexing starting with 0 so you are trying to get item at index that does not exist.

I think you really don't need your inner for loop and this loop is your problem. There you call

```
c.moveToNext();
```

as many times as column's count. So for instance if you have five columns and Cursor has two rows, your moveToNext() method si called 5 times that will cause **CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException**. So remove inner loop and it should works.

I suggest you change your code to following:

```
if (c != null)
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      do {         
         String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
         String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_NAME));
         String singer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_SINGER));
         String genre = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_GENRE));
         String mix = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_MIX));
         String thumb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALB_THUMB));
         albums.add(new Albums(id, name, singer, genre, mix, thumb));
         Log.v("--", "FOUND FROM DB:" + albums.get(i).getTAG_NAME());
      } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
}
```

Comment: He also need to check to check for the FirstRow  place your code inside  `if(c.moveToFirst())` , otherwise he will get Same Exception with index change i.e index 0 and size 0

Comment: @Pragnani he called that. I just update asnwer while you was writing comment.

Comment: No problem brother..I know already know that..but I thought you may forgot to include..

Answer (score 1):

You should use [c.getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) instead of `c.getColumnCount()`, because You're interating through rows, but not columns.